# Tuning Spring JMS for AWS SQS free tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

I'm using Spring JMS to communicate with Amazon SQS queues.  I set up a handful of queues and wired up the listeners, but the app isn't sending any messages through them currently. AWS allows 1 million requests per month for free, which I thought should be no problem, but after a month I got billed a small amount for going over that limit.

Is there a way to tune SQS or Spring JMS to keep the requests down?

I'm assuming a request is whenever my app polls the queue to check for new messages. Some queues don't need to be near realtime so I could definitely reduce those requests.  I'd appreciate any insights you can offer into how SQS and Spring JMS communicate.

Answer (score 0):

"Normal" JMS clients, when polled for messages, don't poll the server - the server pushes messages to the client and the poll is just done locally.

If the SQS client polls the server, that would be unusual, to say the least, but if it's using REST calls, I can see why it would happen.

Increasing the container's `receiveTimeout` (default 1 second) might help, but without knowing what the client is doing under the covers, it's hard to tell.